# Getting error when trying to parse JSON Response - Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type ''

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, jsonparser

Getting error when trying to parse JSON response

```
try
{
   var result = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<Rootobject>(jsonResponse);
}
catch(Exception ex){}
```

JSON string

```
"[{\"ID\":1,\"Code\":null,\"Name\":\"Black\"},{\"ID\":1,\"Code\":null,\"Name\":\"Red\"},{\"ID\":1,\"Code\":\"blx\",\"Name\":\"Blue\"}]"
```

Screenshot is attached for error details and exact JSON String

[image]

I am generating JSON with following code

```
   public string JSONTest()
   {
        List<Color> colors = new List<Color>(); 
        colors.Add(new Color() { ID = 1, Name = "Black" }); 
        colors.Add(new Color() { ID = 1, Name = "Red" }); 
        colors.Add(new Color() { ID = 1, Name = "Blue", Code = "blx" }); 

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(colors); 
    }
```

Comment: I have also tried Class1 instead of RootObject but same error.(You can see Class1 and RootObject classes in attached screenshot.) JSON string is valid as I validated in https://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: Your json got encoded twice.

Comment: You need to modify your json string as {  "Property1" : [ ] }

Comment: The json you have shown can be serialized to `IEnumerable<Class1>` (not to `Rootobject`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - {"Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Class1]'"}

Comment: @tkausl - Why json encoded twice? I have added "json genrating" code in my question

Comment: You cannot possibly be getting that error based on the code and json you have shown.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Using this code to get JSON that is encoded twice. How can fix this - using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) { string jsonResponse = client.DownloadString(colorUrl); }

Comment: Can you address the issue in the method your calling (or don't you have any control over that?)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var result = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<List<Class1>>(jsonResponse);
```

your result will be a list of Class1

[image]

Comment: {"Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Class1]'"}

Comment: I tried the code in LinqPad and it was able to deserialized the json string.

Comment: Getting error with your code. I guess issue is with my json string. Encoded twice I guess.

Comment: Yeah, your image is showing double encoded string. You need to check what's causing this in between your json-generating function and your parser function.

Comment: using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {                 
                    string jsonResponse = client.DownloadString(colorUrl);
                    JSONParseTest(jsonResponse);
                }

Answer (score 0):

Hey try using below:

```
 Class1 obj=new Class1();
 obj=serializer.Deserialize<Class1>(jsonResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON string` deserialization needs the **Root Key** to complete the deserialization process

**In your case**, this JSON does not know which object to deserialize

> You must be show to deserialize class in JSON string..

```
 public class Rootobject
 {         
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
 }


 public class Class1
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
 }



     string jsonResponse = "{ \"Property1\" :  [{\"ID\":1,\"Code\":null,\"Name\":\"Black\"},{\"ID\":1,\"Code\":null,\"Name\":\"Red\"},{\"ID\":1,\"Code\":\"blx\",\"Name\":\"Blue\"}] }";

     var result = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<Rootobject>(jsonResponse);
```

**Generate JSON string with Root Key**

```
    public string JSONTest()
    {

        List<Class1> colors = new List<Class1>();
        colors.Add(new Class1() { ID = 1, Name = "Black" });
        colors.Add(new Class1() { ID = 1, Name = "Red" });
        colors.Add(new Class1() { ID = 1, Name = "Blue", Code = "blx" });

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Rootobject { Property1 = colors.ToArray() });
    }
```

Alternatifly,

`DeserializeObject` method can be deserialized on `object` directly.
 if you use it like this you will not need Root Key **but return value will be an object..**

```
 string jsonResponse = "[{\"ID\":1,\"Code\":null,\"Name\":\"Black\"},{\"ID\":1,\"Code\":null,\"Name\":\"Red\"},{\"ID\":1,\"Code\":\"blx\",\"Name\":\"Blue\"}]";
                object[] result = (object[])(new JavaScriptSerializer()).DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);
```

Comment: Your code is working fine. How can I append "Property1" in JSON string. Not asking to append in json string. Asking from where json generates (You can see JSON string generation code in end of question above).

Comment: @Alex I updated answer , added Generate JSON string with Root Key